# Laravel:Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5.3

i want the current user when add user in a team will save in database user id for this user not id for current user but when i use `$user=User::all();` or `$user=User::find($id);` don't work and have error:

```
 Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id
```

and when use `$user=Auth::user();` save the current user id

```
public function addUser($id)
{

            $teams =TeamWork::find($id);

            $user =User::all();

            $teammember = new TeamMember;
            $teammember->user()->associate($user->id);
            $teammember->Teamwork()->associate($teams->id);
            $teammember->save();

            $users = User::pluck('username');

        return View('teams.adduser' , compact('users'))->with('teams', $teams);


      }
```

Comment: try to prepend toArray() to this: `$users = User::pluck('username')->toArray();` does it change anything

Comment: @lewis4u the same

Comment: well this line of code is wrong: `$teammember->user()->associate($user->id);` you are pulling all the users from DB and you say $user->id....that is not one user...you need to find it like with TeamWork, something like `$user = User::find()`

Comment: i made that to get all user when user search for someone to add to team and save his user_id in teammember table

Comment: OK but try `dd($user->id);` under `$user =User::all();` and you will see what you get...

Comment: when i use $user =User::all(); or $user =User::find($id);
i have this issue Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

Comment: yes because you are calling all users and then you say give me id. i hope you understand the error....you want a single value from array....you need to specify from which user you want that id

Comment: `User::all()` returns collection of User modal instances, To get id from user you need single modal instance

Comment: استخدمى  User::find() 
لانها بترجعلك ال object
لكن User::all() بترجعلك   array

Answer (score 1):

Salam Alikom, 
You have two `$id` here, `$user->id` and `$team->id`, 
Firstly, you can't use `$user->id` because `all()` method returns `array not object`. So you have to use `$userId = Auth::user()->id` instead. and`var_dump($team)` to make assure that it has property `id`.

Comment: still save id of current user id not the other one